# Parse Cloud Cloud - Only accept calls from my domain

Tags: express, parse-platform

I have concerns that someone can use my parse client key, build their own app and connect to Parse, create users and execute my cloud code functions.

Is there any way I can lock this down so that Parse only accepts requests that originate from my web domain, for example, www.mydomain.com,  if so, 
how would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really, and any check on the headers isn't reliable as it's easy to fake.

Instead you should create your own authentication system for your requests. Again, this can be reverse engineered, but will be harder. The scheme could be something like a timestamp and a salted hash of that timestamp that the server can verify (because it knows the salt).

Comment: Good thinking, I am going to explore the Parse express middleware to see if it can help, I noticed that there was CSRF functionality but not sure how it ties into Parse fully.

Answer (score 1):

Your client key is public information and not a secret so do not treat it as if it is one. Also you data will be either public or protected (using ACLs, CLPs or secure cloud code). So if someone gets your key and builds an interface, they will be able to access anything ***you*** may choose to leave as public information. You really cannot have public data that is only available via your own app even if you implement measures to make it difficult to extract.

Comment: Good points, I somewhat addressed the issue where users can be created on the fly by using the google recapcha v2, it would add additional complexity and keep bots away.